# Line 22: No source code is available for type in html libgdx

Tags: java, javascript, web-services, gwt, libgdx

i'm trying to run html libgdx project, where i have a splash screen that uses tweenengine

[ERROR] Line 22: No source code is available for type aurelienribon.tweenengine.TweenManager

any idea how to fix this?
thanks

Answer (score 2):

GWT requires java source code files of all client-side dependencies so it can run those through it's Java-to-Javascript compiler.

Have you included TweenEngine jar file in your libgdx project? Make sure that the jar includes the source (*.java) files.